# Trouble Understanding Distributive Law in Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I understand the first distributive law:

$$P\land(Q\lor R)=(P\land Q)\lor (P\land R).$$

However, I don't understand the second:

$$P\lor (Q\land R)=(P\lor Q)\land(P\lor R).$$

It seems to me that the right side expresses that the possibilities are $P$, $PR$, $PQ$, $QR$, and $PQR$, while the left side only allows for the possibilities $P$, $QR$, and $PQR$, as $Q$ & $R$ are "bound together" on the left side so $PR$ & $PQ$ aren't possible.

Answer (score 1):

The left side does allow PQ and PR. P being true is sufficient for PV(Q&R) to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $P$ is true then the left side is true therefore $PR$ and $PQ$ make the left side true as well.

Answer (score 0):

Double negative and De Morgan's laws imply one distributive law from the other:

$$\neg (P\vee (Q\wedge R)) = \neg P \wedge \neg (Q\wedge R) = \neg P \wedge (\neg Q \vee \neg R) = (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)\vee(\neg P \wedge \neg R)$$ $$= \neg(P\vee Q)\vee\neg(P\vee R) = \neg((P\vee Q)\wedge(P\vee R))$$